# Connect MacBook Pro to Dell Monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, resolution, dvi

Hello I am trying to connect my late 2013 MacBook Pro with mini DisplayPort/ Thunderbolt to Dell 3007WFP 30" monitor. It is connecting fine, but the resolution is very poor. What is the best DVI adaptor; I'm looking at Apple, Kanex iAdapt, or Monoprice. What would be the best option to get 2560x1600 resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this exact same monitor that acquired about a 18 months ago (or so).  That particular monitor requires a [Dual Link DVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) connection and most mDP to DVI aren't Dual Link.

The one product that I found that worked really well was [Kanex iAdapt Mini DisplayPort / Thunderbolt to DVI Adapter + USB](http://radnex.us/kanex-iadapt-thunderbolt-mdp-to-DVI-cable)

I tested this on an iMac 27 (Catalina), a 2009 MacBook Pro (El Capitan), and a Surface Pro 3 (Windows 10).  All were able to display full resolution with no problem.  I'm now using it on a Dell workstation running FreeBSD 12.1-RELEASE and I've had zero issues with the adapter.